# $R$ is a division Ring. $R-Z(R)$ is finite. How to prove $R$ is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$R$ is a division Ring. $Z(R)$ is the center of ring and $R-Z(R)$ is finite. How should I prove that $R$ is finite?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: This is assuming that $R$ is not a field, right?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have no idea

Comment: @MiloBrandt I know every finite division ring is a field. But here we are not assuming that $R$ is a field.

Comment: $Z(R)$ is a subgroup of $R$ under addition. Unless $R=Z(R)$ then $R-Z(R)$ contains a coset of $Z(R)$. Doesn't that mean that $Z(R)$ must be finite?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown How did you exactly conclude that $Z(R)$ is finite?

Comment: Agree with Lord Shark. Let $a\in R\setminus Z(R)$. Then $a+Z(R)$ has the same cardinality as $Z(R)$ and $a+Z(R)$ is contained in $R\setminus Z(R)$.

Comment: Mind you, it then follows from Wedderburn's theorem that $R$ is actually a field, but may be should not get ahead of ourselves.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen; Why do we need that $R$ is a division ring to prove this?Can't we take it to be a ring only

Comment: @Maths_Is_Fun A good point. We don't need that assumption at all! I guess that will be used in a follow up. Well. Actually it follows from Wedderburn that if $R\setminus Z(R)$ is finite then $R=Z(R)$ and we cannot conclude that $R$ would be finite. Milo Brandt brought up that point already.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:  In my answer below,  I used the hypothesis that $R$ is a division ring to establish that $z^{-1} \in Z(R)$ exists.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:  you refer to Wedderburn's ***Every finite division ring is a field***, right?  But how do we know $R$ is finite without knowing $Z(R)$ is finite?

Comment: @RobertLewis Correct. I'm trying to conclude that if $R\setminus Z(R)$ is finite, then $R\setminus Z(R)$ is actually empty. And the claim is actually false :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $R \setminus Z(R)$ is finite, we need to show that $Z(R)$ is finite.

Now

$Z(R) = \{z \in R \mid zr = rz, \; \forall r \in R \}; \tag 1$

as such, $Z(R)$ is a field.  It is clear that $Z(R)$ is a subring of $R$; if $0 \ne z \in Z(R)$, then since for $r \in R$,

$zr = rz, \tag 2$

we have

$rz^{-1} = z^{-1}r, \tag 3$

which shows $z^{-1} \in Z(R)$; thus $Z(R)$ is a field, a subfield of the division ring $R$.

Now let $r \in R \setminus Z(R)$; we have, for $0 \ne z \in Z(R)$,

$zr \in R \setminus Z(R); \tag 4$

for if $zr \in Z(R)$, then

$r = z^{-1}(zr) \in Z(R), \tag 5$

a contradiction.  Furthermrore, for $r \in R \setminus Z(R)$, the map $\theta_r:Z(R) \setminus \{0\} \to R \setminus Z(R)$ given by

$\theta_r(z) = zr \tag 6$

is injective, since

$z_1r = z_2r \Longrightarrow z_1 = (z_1r)r^{-1} = (z_2r)r^{-1} = z_2; \tag 7$

now since $R \setminus Z(R)$ is finite, the set $\theta_r(Z(R) \setminus \{0\}) \subset R \setminus Z(R)$ is also finite; since $\theta_r$ is injective, we must have $Z(R) \setminus \{0\}$, and hence $Z(R)$, are finite as well.  And that's that.

***Note Added in Edit, Saturday 21 October 2017 9:23 AM PST:***  First off, lauds to Milo Brandt and Lord Shark, who advanced the notion of a proof based on the additive cosets $r + Z(R)$; quite elegant.  What I saw, when first reading this problem, was that, since $Z(R)$ is a sub-*field* of $R$, we can, in a manner analogous to field extensions, conceive of $R$ as a vector space over $Z(R)$; then the whole rigamarole about $\theta_r(z) = zr$ is based on the notion that $\theta_r(Z(R))$ is a one-dimensinal vector subspace of $R$; the rest is just a simple counting argument.  ***End of Note.***

Answer (score 2):

Note that $Z(R)$ is an additive subgroup of $(R,+$). Consider the quotient map $\pi:R\rightarrow (R,+)/Z(R)$. The fibers of this map are all equally large and $Z(R)$ is the kernel. Assuming that $R$ is not a field, we have that $R\setminus Z(R)$ is not empty. Thus, $R\setminus Z(R)$ is a non-empty union of fibers of $\pi$, each of which has size $Z(R)$. Thus, $Z(R)$ must be finite, so $R$ is too.

Comment: No need to consider fibers: $d+Z(R)\subseteq R\setminus Z(R)$, if $d\in R\setminus Z(R)$. Therefore $d+Z(R)$ is finite, so that also $Z(R)$ is finite. The assumption that $R$ is not a field is necessary, because if $R$ is an infinite field then $R\setminus Z(R)$ is finite.